# Regular express to match characters and digits but not specific strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Good evening guys,

I have a question to the regular expression in Java.

I have a string s and it should  begin with a lower case or upper case character and followed by no matter how many characters or digits .It should not match keywords(all in lower case) "if","else","while","true","false"

So it will be something like this in Java

```
    if(s.matches("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*") && !s.equals("if") 
                    && !s.equals("else") && !s.equals("while") &&  !s.equals("true") 
                    && !s.equals("false")){
              System.out.println("is ID");
}

        else {
                  System.out.println("not ID");
    }
```

So the output to different s looks like

```
 //s="if"
not ID

 //s="ifif"
is ID

//s="while220"
is ID

//s="90"
not ID
```

My question is: 
Can I use one regular expression to reach all the conditions in my if statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do all in a single regex though [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This won't match if the input string is `if` or `else` or `while` or `true` or `false`. Below pattern would match the strings other than these keywords which actually satisfies `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` .

```
if(s.matches("^(?!(?:if|else|while|true|false)$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"))
{
System.out.println("is ID");
}

    else {
              System.out.println("not ID");
}
```